# Returning agents to pool in in Waterdeep Harbor phase

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

If I move an agent from Waterdeep Harbour and complete a quest which allows me to return agents to my pool, can I assign those agents again this round?

If so, can these agents be placed in the harbour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can reassign the returned agents; you do so immediately before continuing with the Waterdeep Harbour phase. But no, you cannot place them in the Harbour. From the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Lords_of_Waterdeep_FAQ):

> Q: If I complete the "Recruit Lieutenant" quest as a result of reassigning an agent from "Waterdeep Harbor", do I get to assign that agent immediately?
>
> > **A: Yes. If any effect puts a new agent into your pool during reassignment from "Waterdeep Harbor", you assign that agent immediately. However, you can't assign him to "Waterdeep Harbor" (he follows the same rule as the "Research Chronomancy" quest, a returned/new agent can't be assigned to "Waterdeep Harbor" during the reassignment phase of the round).**